# How can I use RGB codes in discord.Colour in Python?

Tags: python, colors, discord.py

Recently I've been trying to use RGB Colours, i.e.
`166, 245, 255`.
However I'm stuck in here:
`discord.Colour()`
where I can only input ONE value in the brackets. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

For 0-255 RGB range: `discord.Colour.from_rgb(r, g, b)`

For hexa: `discord.Colour(0xff55ff)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`discord.Colour.from_rgb`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Colour.from_rgb) class method, e.g.
`colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(166, 245, 255)`.